# How to match ID in column in unix?

Tags: unix, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools

I am fully aware that similar questions may have been posted, but after searching it seems that the details of our questions are different (or at least I did not manage to find a solution that can be adopted in my case).

I currently have two files: **"messyFile"** and **"wantedID"**. **"messyFile"** is of size **80,000,000 X 2,500**, whereas **"wantedID"** is of size **1 x 462**. On the 253rd line of **"messyFile"**, there are 2500 IDs. However, all I want is the 462 IDs in the file **"wantedID"**. Assuming that the 462 IDs are a subset of the 2500 IDs, how can I process the file **"messyFile"** such that it only contains information about the 462 IDs (ie. of size **80,000,000 X 462**).

Thank you so much for your patience!

ps: Sorry for the confusion. But yeah, the question can be boiled down to something like this. In the 1st row of **"File#1"**, there are 10 IDs. In the 1st row of **"File#2"**, there are 3 IDs (**"File#2"** consists of only 1 line). The 3 IDs are a subset of the 10 IDs. Now, I hope to process **"File#1"** so that it contains only information about the 3 IDs listed in **"File#2"**.

ps2: **"messyFile"** is a vcf file, whereas **"wantedID"** can be a text file (I said "can be" because it is small, so I can make almost any type for it)

ps3: "File#1" should look something like this:

```
sample#1 sample#2 sample#3 sample#4 sample#5
    0        1       0        0        1
    1        1       2        0        2
```

"File#2" should look something like this:

```
sample#2 sample#4 sample#5
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
sample#2 sample#4 sample#5
   1        0        1
   1        0        2
```

Comment: Unclear about the format of your data. It sounds like a mess! ;-) Can you give us a really small set of sample data for messyFile and WantedID. If it can work for 10 rows messy, by 3 rows wanted, it should probably also work for your larger files. the confusing part is `On the 253rd line of "messyFile", there are 2500 IDs. However, all I want is the 462 IDs in the file "wantedID". ` Reduce this in your example data to "the 3rd line has 10 IDs, and I want is the 4 IDS in file "wantedID". We need to see expected output to be any help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just edited it in my original post.

Comment: please use data that people can copy/paste into their environment and then develop a solution. As is, **we** get to make up the data, only to have you tell us "oh yeah, what about this other case I forgot to mention" (!) OK? Good luck.

Comment: I apologize that I can hardly get the actual data (even extract it in smaller piece), because it is simply too big and messy. However, I manage to come up with something look like them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parsing VCF format, use `bcftools`:

http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html

Specifically for your task see the `view` command:

http://samtools.github.io/bcftools/bcftools.html#view

Example:

```
bcftools view -Ov -S 462sample.list -r chr:pos -o subset.vcf superset.vcf
```

You will need to get the position of the SNP to specify `chr:pos` above.

You can do this using DbSNP:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/SNP/index.html

Just make sure to match the genome build to the one used in the VCF file.

You can also use `plink`:

https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2

But, PLINK is finicky about duplicated SNPs and other things, so it may complain unless you address these issues.

I've done what you are attempting in the past using the `awk` programming language. For your sanity, I recommend using one of the above tools :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have no idea what a vcf file is but if the File#1 and File#2 samples you gave were files containing tab separated columns this will work:

```
declare -a data=(`head -1 data.txt`)
declare -a header=(`head -1 header.txt`)

declare fields
declare -i count
for i in "${header[@]}" ; do
  count=0
  for j in "${data[@]}" ; do
    count=$count+1;
    if [ $i == $j ] ; then
      fields=$fields,$count
    fi
  done
done

cut -f ${fields:1} data.txt
```

If they aren't tab separated values perhaps it can be amended for the actual data format.